# I don't know what verision of Ruby I am using

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

n00b here, but it looks like I have 4 versions of Ruby. How do I delete the ones I don't want and how do I keep the most up to date one? Also, shouldn't both of these commands have the same output?

```
eamon@ubuntu:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]  
eamon@ubuntu:~$ rvm all do ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]
ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: This question is not off-topic. RVM is commonly used for managing multiple Ruby installations, and Stack Overflow is a major source of information for handling this sort of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ruby -v` shows the current version that you're using. And `rvm` is the Ruby Version Manager and allows you to change your environment easily. so the output is reasonable because you have installed 1.8.7, 2.0.0, 2.1.0 and 1.9.2 but currently you're using 1.8.7. For more information you should learn more about [rvm](http://rvm.io/).

Comment: but rvm says I don't even have 1.8.7, so why am I using that?

Comment: You must have 1.8.7 installed, otherwise you can't use this binary. You can't see 1.8.7 in rvm list because you may install ruby by apt-get or source code rather than using rvm.

By the way, you can `rvm use 2.1.0` to choose any version you want. After doing this, I recommend you to refer the official document to see more features about rvm.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`rvm remove`](http://rvm.io/rubies/removing) to remove the versions you don't want.

Comment: Alright I removed the unwanted verisions; but I want to be using 2.1.0, but yet ruby -v still out puts ruby 1.8.7

Comment: `rvm use 2.1.0 --default` will tell RVM to default to a particular version when you open a shell.